# Iterating csvDictReader with nested for loops

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I am having difficulty understanding how to properly iterate over a csvDictReader object.  I am trying to return each csv value tied to a specific user-defined datacode.  Since I am generating the dict from a web query I would like to re-use it in memory rather than poll the web again for data that is already in memory.

```
import sys, csv, urllib2
class SmfImpl():

    def __init__( self, ctx ):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.csv_dict = []
        self.flag = ['Not Available', '']
        self.ticker = 'XOM'

    def getMorningKey(self, datacode):
        return fetch_keyratios(self, datacode)

#these functions are not in the SmfImpl class because they're from a seperate file
def query_morningstar(self, url_ending): 
        url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XNYS:%s%s' % (self.ticker, url_ending)
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = sniff_query(req)
        response.readline()
        return csv.DictReader(response)

def sniff_query(req):
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        return 'Check Connection'
    sniff = response.readline()
    if str(sniff) == '':
        return 'Not Available'
    return response

def fetch_keyratios(self, datacode):
    if datacode < 1 or datacode > 990:
        return 'Invalid Datacode'
    #check if we already have the data we need
    if self.flag[0] == 'Check Connection' or self.flag[0] == 'Not Available' or self.flag[1] != self.ticker:
        #query remote and check for errors
        self.csv_dict = query_morningstar(self,'&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&order=desc')
        if self.csv_dict == 'Check Connection' or self.csv_dict == 'Not Available':
            self.flag[1] = ''
            return self.csv_dict
        else:
            self.flag[0] = ''
            self.flag[1] = self.ticker
    return sort_keyratios(self, datacode)

def sort_keyratios(self, datacode):       
    counter = 1
    skipped = 0
    skip_lines = [15, 16, 26, 36, 37, 57, 58, 64, 65, 86, 91, 92]            
    #iterate through returned dict line by line
    for line in self.csv_dict:
        for item in skip_lines:
            if counter == item:
                skipped += 1
        for val in range(1, len(line)):
            #match year values to datacodes
            if datacode == val:
                return self.csv_dict.fieldnames[val]
            #match data values to datacodes
            if datacode-((counter-skipped)*(len(line)-1)) == val:
                return line[self.csv_dict.fieldnames[val]]
        counter += 1
    return 'No Data'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smf = SmfImpl(sys.argv)
    ticker = 'XOM'
    for val in range (1,24):
        print ticker, val,':', smf.getMorningKey(val)
```

The original csv is called for by the script, but it can also be found [here](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=XOM&region=USA&culture=en-US)

The output that I'm getting is:

```
XOM 1 : TTM
XOM 2 : 2012-12
XOM 3 : 2011-12
XOM 4 : 2010-12
XOM 5 : 2009-12
XOM 6 : 2008-12
XOM 7 : 2007-12
XOM 8 : 2006-12
XOM 9 : 2005-12
XOM 10 : 2004-12
XOM 11 : 2003-12
XOM 12 : -35,300
XOM 13 : 21,899
XOM 14 : 5.00
XOM 15 : -3,649
XOM 16 : None
XOM 17 : 2008-12
XOM 18 : 100.00
XOM 19 : 56.47
XOM 20 : 42.54
XOM 21 : 4.65
XOM 22 : 
XOM 23 : 13.67
```

What I am trying to get:

```
XOM 1 : TTM
XOM 2 : 2012-12
XOM 3 : 2011-12
XOM 4 : 2010-12
XOM 5 : 2009-12
XOM 6 : 2008-12
XOM 7 : 2007-12
XOM 8 : 2006-12
XOM 9 : 2005-12
XOM 10 : 2004-12
XOM 11 : 2003-12
XOM 12 : 443,708
XOM 13 : 482,295
XOM 14 : 486,429
XOM 15 : 383,221
XOM 16 : 310,586
XOM 17 : 477,359
XOM 18 : 404,552
XOM 19 : 377,635
XOM 20 : 370,680
XOM 21 : 298,035
XOM 22 : 246,738
XOM 23 : 27.8
```

EDIT: I am trying to map the datacodes in groups per line of the original csv. e.g Years would be datacodes 1 to 11 (TTM to 2003-12), Revenue would be datacodes 12 to 22 (443708 to 246738) etc. Ultimately these datacodes will be moved to user input, so they may be accessed in any order.

Comment: Will the vals/datacodes always be accessed in ascending order like that? Would it be feasible to read the entire csv into memory?

Comment: No, both ticker and val that are defined in main will ultimately be moved to user input / sys.argv, so the values may be accessed in any order.

Comment: Well, for one thing, that would mean re-reading at least some portion of the csv data each time because `csv.DictReader` accesses the data in a sequential manor -- which was why I suggested reading the whole thing into memory which would allow random access (as well as retaining it between calls). Also your question needs to have additional information added to it explaining the mapping of datacodes to locations in the csv file because it's not clear enough from the code and handful of comments in it. Frankly it's not clear to me why you're even using `csv.DictReader` to try to do this.

Comment: I have edited the original post to clarify the datacode mapping.  I had originally implemented this as 1 urlrequest -> 1 script output, and csvDictReader seemed like the proper approach.  I think that now that I am re-using the data locally, csvDictReader may not be the best approach, but I am not certain how to implement this functionality in memory as you suggest.

Comment: OK, that helps. If that's the case shouldn't the desired value for `XOM 23` be `27.8` not `28.7`? Also, is the `counter` & `skip_lines` stuff in `sort_keyratios()` an artifact of your own attempt to fix the problem?

Comment: After looking at the raw response data, I can see the complexity involved in parsing it with the `csv` module -- since it's actually a stream of several different csv files, each following the other with its own set of fields/columns. It's doable if the format of the response is constant for every request.

Comment: Indeed, `XOM 23` should be `27.8`, typo fixed, and `counter` and `skip_lines` _are_ artifacts of trying to get `csv.DictReader` working. The formatting is consistent across requests, as I can change ticker from `XOM` to `COP`, `AAPL` etc. and get the same result. I'm just not sure how to manipulate this data in memory without the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. It will produce the output you want. I've reformatted the code a little bit to fit better in the code listing boxes here on stackoverflow. The tricky part was figuring-out the mapping of `datacode` to `row, column` of data read into a matrix in memory.

```
import sys, csv, urllib2
class SmfImpl():
    def __init__( self, ctx ):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.csv_reader = ''
        self.flag = ['Not Available', '']
        self.ticker = 'XOM'

    def getMorningKey(self, datacode):
        return fetch_keyratios(self, datacode)

#these functions are not in the SmfImpl class because they're in a seperate file
def query_morningstar(self, url_ending):
    MORNING_STAR = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html'
    url = MORNING_STAR + '?&callback=?&t=XNYS:%s%s' % (self.ticker, url_ending)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = sniff_query(req)
    response.readline()
    return csv.reader(response)

def sniff_query(req):
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        return 'Check Connection'
    sniff = response.readline()
    if str(sniff) == '':
        return 'Not Available'
    return response

def fetch_keyratios(self, datacode):
    if datacode < 1 or datacode > 990:
        return 'Invalid Datacode'
    #check if we already have the data we need
    if(self.flag[0] == 'Check Connection' or
       self.flag[0] == 'Not Available' or self.flag[1] != self.ticker):
        #query remote and check for errors
        self.csv_reader = query_morningstar(self,
                                '&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&order=desc')
        if(self.csv_reader == 'Check Connection' or
           self.csv_reader == 'Not Available'):
            self.flag[1] = ''
            return self.csv_reader  # actually response status message
        else:
            self.flag[0] = ''
            self.flag[1] = self.ticker
            # read entire dataset in memory skipping lines as neccessary
            self.data = [row[1:] for row in self.csv_reader if len(row) == 12]

    return sort_keyratios(self, datacode)

def sort_keyratios(self, datacode):
    # convert datacode to row, column and return data in that position of list
    row, col = divmod(datacode-1, 11)
    return self.data[row][col]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smf = SmfImpl(sys.argv)
    ticker = 'XOM'
    for val in range(1, 24):
        print ticker, val,':', smf.getMorningKey(val)
```

A `csv.reader()` is used instead of a `csv.DictReader` since you weren't really making use of the column/field names. All the data in the response (except the few first lines) is read in using it and stored in a list-of-lists the first time `getMorningKey()` is called. Each row read this way should be a list of 12 items and any that do not are skipped. Also only the last 11 entries are saved in order to make the mapping from datacode easier.  The results is a 2-dimensional matrix where the row is the line number and the column is the field number. A view of the raw matrix data for Exxon example ticker is shown on this [web page](https://db.tt/brXXdOY3) I created.

As you can see this approach greatly simplifies the logic and, since it stores all the data in memory, it will be reused in subsequent calls and makes random access possible without doing the query again.

Here's the output:

```
XOM 1 : TTM
XOM 2 : 2012-12
XOM 3 : 2011-12
XOM 4 : 2010-12
XOM 5 : 2009-12
XOM 6 : 2008-12
XOM 7 : 2007-12
XOM 8 : 2006-12
XOM 9 : 2005-12
XOM 10 : 2004-12
XOM 11 : 2003-12
XOM 12 : 443,708
XOM 13 : 482,295
XOM 14 : 486,429
XOM 15 : 383,221
XOM 16 : 310,586
XOM 17 : 477,359
XOM 18 : 404,552
XOM 19 : 377,635
XOM 20 : 370,680
XOM 21 : 298,035
XOM 22 : 246,738
XOM 23 : 27.8
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. Truly, thank you very much.  I posted an answer that completes the functionality that I was looking for, in case it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

This is to respond to the modifications you made to `sort_keyratios()` in the answer you posted to your own question. It's also so you have something else to up-vote, should you find the additional information useful. <hint>

Anyway, you could do what is being done *much* more efficiently by building a dictionary that maps each `datacode` to a `(row, col)` pair once, and then just using this previously built table to look up the values in the function. TO facilitate that I've added a new function called `create_datacode_map()`.

Here's how it could be used:

```
def create_datacode_map():
    """ Create dictionary mapping datacodes to (row, col) in data. """
    # define rows that have no useful data
    skip_list = {16, 17, 18, 28, 29, 38, 39, 40, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 62, 63, 69,
                 70, 71, 92, 93, 98, 99, 100}
    def find_row_col(datacode):
        skipped = 0
        # match datacode to row, column
        for row in xrange(0, 109):
            if row in skip_list:
                skipped += 11
                continue
            for col in xrange(0, 12):
                if datacode == col + (11*row) - skipped:
                    return row, col

    # create and return the dictionary
    return {datacode: find_row_col(datacode) for datacode in xrange(1, 910)}

def sort_keyratios(self, datacode):
    # convert datacode to row, column and return data in that position of list
    if not hasattr(self, 'datacode_map'):
        self.datacode_map = create_datacode_map()
    row, col = self.datacode_map[datacode]  # lookup conversion
    return self.data[row][col]
```

The version of `sort_keyratios()` shown checks for the existence of `self.datacode_map` each time it's called and creates it if it doesn't exist. It would be more efficient to have done that already in `fetch_keyratios(()` so `sort_keyratios()` could assume it exists and not have to check each time it's called.

Comment: It feels like coming full circle mapping back to a dict. I'm sure you have deduced that I am 'learning python the hard way'.  Thank you for the explanations and subtleties in your code that help me guide my own learning(i.e. `xrange()` vs `range()`, though I may find myself at the mercy of Python 3, so may stick with `range()`). Why do you make `find_row_col()` a sub-function rather than leaving that code in `create_datacode_map()`?

Comment: Yes, it's yet another dictionary, but its purpose is completely different. Python has tools for converting from version 2 to 3 that will fix uses of `xrange` so I wouldn't avoid it for that reason. I made `find_row_col()` a nested function because it's only called by `create_datacode_map()` and it allows `skip_list` to be created outside the function itself rather than every times it's called.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Martineau posted is correct.  To finish off and get the functionality I was originally looking for I changed sort_keyratios to the following:

```
def sort_keyratios:    
    #define rows that have no useful data   
    skip_list = [16,17,18,28,29,38,39,40,41,46,51,56,61,62,63,69,70,71,92,93,98,99,100]
    skipped = 0
    # match datacode to row, column and return data in that position of list
    for row in range(0,109):
        if row in skip_list:
            skipped+=11
            continue
        for col in range(0,12):
            if datacode == col+(11*row)-skipped:
                return self.data[row][col]
```